# Android studio not working in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

I formated my pc 3 times with ubuntu 15.04 and tried installing the Android Studio  but its not working.

I am jut seeing the message `Gradle : Resolve dependencies`. its running for long time more than 30 mins.

and once its done i try to run the application. but its never build the project just seeing the message `processing`

here is the image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 14.04. This is not due to the Ubuntu. This error appeared after updating my Android Studio to 1.3.
To solve the problem, follow these steps:

Step 1:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Step 2:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

It should fix the problem.

Also, it is recommended to use Oracle JDK with Android Studio. I recommend you to [Install Oracle JDK](http://www.javahelps.com/2015/03/install-oracle-jdk-in-ubuntu.html).

Answer (score 0):

As **OpenJDK** is a part of **Linux OS**, ***Android Studio*** detects it and start functioning. But in some devices OpenJDK causes performance issues.

That's why it is suggesting you to install Oracle JDK. I my case installing the Oracle JDK and showing the path from the project structure helped.

Answer (score 0):

2. The Second popup which is in android studio window is probably a bug and there is a workaround also (take a look at [this](http://tools.android.com/knownissues/ibus))

> On Linux systems (where the ibus-daemon is active), there are scenarios where the IDE will stop responding to keyboard input or start inputting random characters. This document provides some workarounds for those bugs

1. The First warning is about Openjdk , for android studio to work properly you need to consider installing OracleJDK rather than Open JDK

You can install it from [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521145/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-14-04) 
webupd8team ppa you can use it to install Oracle java or download and extract from Oracle